# SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, post

I'm making a plugin. I'm trying to simply update post meta in Wordpress, by posting an array/object/json array to this php code:

```
public static function save_settings_fields(){

    $myArray = json_decode($_POST['to_save']);
    wp_send_json(var_dump($_POST['to_save']));

    //i can't even get to this point.
    $saved_content = json_decode($_POST['to_save']);
    $post_id = $saved_content['post_id'];
    $this_count = (int)$saved_content['index'];
    $foobar = new POB_Save_Settings;
    $isdone = $foobar->update_static_content($post_id, $this_count, $saved_content);
    if ( is_wp_error( $isdone ) ) {

        wp_send_json_error( $isdone );

    } else {
      wp_send_json( $isdone );
    }
  }
```

my script is:

```
var SaveOptionSettings = function(postid, count){
    var save_array = new Array();
    save_array[0]= {};
    save_array[0]['post_id'] = postid;
    save_array[0]['content_count'] = count;
    save_array[1] = {};
    for(var i=0; i<$('#settings input').length; i++){
      save_array[1][$('#settings input').eq(i).attr('id')] = $('#settings input').eq(i).val();
    }
    for(var i=0; i<$('#settings textarea').length; i++){
      save_array[1][$('#settings textarea').eq(i).attr('id')] = $('#settings textarea').eq(i).val();
    }
    for(var i=0; i<$('#settings select').length; i++){
      save_array[1][$('#settings select').eq(i).attr('id')] = $('#settings select').eq(i).val();
    }
    console.log(save_array, JSON.stringify(save_array));
    var pva_ajax_url = pva_params.pva_ajax_url;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pva_ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'save_settings_fields',
            'to_save': JSON.stringify(save_array)
        }, success: function (result) {
          M.toast({html: 'Saved!'})
        },
        error: function(xhr,textStatus,err)
        {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
            console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
            console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
            console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("error: " + err);
        }
    });
  }
```

The `wp_send_json` pretty much just sends me back what `$_POST` is getting, which apparently is:

```
readyState: 4
responseText: 
string(202) "[{\"post_id\":15404,\"content_count\":1},{\"label\":\"Options <span>(please select one)</span>\",\"use_conditionals\":\"on\",\"classes\":\"form-buttons\",\"style_id\":\"options\",\"subtitle\":\"test\"}]"
null
status: 200
text status: parsererror
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1
```

**What I've Tried:**

- using `json_decode` on that posted info
- adding `contentType: "application/json"` to the AJAX
- all combinations of removing Stringify, dataType, changing dataType to Text
- making every variable get `.push`ed into an array
- making the array an object, and vice versa

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your server response start with string (202) , 
and this is not valid json

```
string(202) "[{\"post_id\":15404,\"content_count\":1},{\"label\":\"Options <span>(please select one)</span>\",\"use_conditionals\":\"on\",\"classes\":\"form-buttons\",\"style_id\":\"options\",\"subtitle\":\"test\"}]"
null
```

and

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1
```

this s from String

you responseText shall be something like

```
[{
    "post_id": 15404,
    "content_count": 1
}, {
    "label": "Options <span>(please select one)</span>",
    "use_conditionals": "on",
    "classes": "form-buttons",
    "style_id": "options",
    "subtitle": "test"
}]
```

// update

@lawrence-cherone php-side mention

```
var_dump()

wp_send_json(var_dump($_POST['to_save']));
```

this line need to be removed or comment

thanks for @lawrence-cherone

Also, if you'd like to debug content, you may have better success using `echo` or `print_r`.

Using one of these prints the contents of whatever you enter onto the page, which is then returned as `result` in the AJAX `success: function(result){ ... }`.

Comment: So basically remove `wp_send_json(var_dump($_POST['to_save']));`?

Comment: it look like this , but i answer for explaining the error on JS side what does it mean

Comment: // wp_send_json(var_dump($_POST['to_save']));
 this line need to be commented i think removed all as he send Json 2 before code run

Comment: No its all good +1 just pointing out if you look at the OPs php code you see that debugging left in which will be causing the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer, and perhaps I am not explaining it well enough, but I know it's sending invalid JSON, I just can't figure out why. Those extra debug lines are just floating as I'm trying to make the `_POST` data actually do something. Why is it, when I send the data, it adds `string` to the beginning? How do I make it stop?

Comment: @MackenzieFritschle didn't you see? Remove `var_dump` from your output code. Bam.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Now that I think of it, I'm not sure if I tried the `wp_send_json($_POST)` on it's own... I did try `wp_send_json(json_decode($_POST['to_save']))`, though, and the response simply returned `NULL`. Am I wrong to assume the JSON needs to be decoded? Forgive me if it seems obvious, my mind feels like a pretzel after 12 hours of rushing through this

Comment: @MackenzieFritschle ... ah. Well. Hrmpf. At the mercy of some other function that is butchering your data ;)

Comment: Sorry, pretty much everyone here was right. While there were some extraneous things that had to be fixed as well, to achieve the proper debugging I was hoping for, I needed to simply `echo` or `print_r` to return results. Basically, I was overcomplicating everything. Since that was my issue, @JehadAhmadJaghoub add in info about better ways to debug and I'll accept the answer!